# hacer una consulta mysqli por cada iteracion de un ciclo foreach?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer una consulta mysqli por cada resultado de un ciclo foreach, por ejemplo si envió como arreglo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="filtrar.php" method="GET">
<div class="form-wrapper small">

    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <button class="navbar-button form-label" type="button" id="country-btn">PAIS <span class="form-span"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></i></button>

        <?php $paises = Utils::showPais(); ?>
        <div class="country-wrapper" id="country-category">
            <?php while($pais= $paises->fetch_object()): ?> 
                <label class="label-wrapper" for="<?=$pais->nombre?>"><?=$pais->nombre?>
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="id_pais[]" id="<?=$pais->nombre?>" value="<?=$pais->id?>">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>   
                </label>
            <?php endwhile; ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Filtrar">

</div>
</form>
```

Les explico un poco, con la función Utils::showPais(); recojo todos los países que hay en la base de datos y luego los recorro con un ciclo while y genero un checkbox por cada país que existe, luego con una funcion js capturo el name y el value de los checkbox que estén checkeados y los envió por GET al controlador.

CONTROLADOR

```
if (isset($_GET['id_pais']) && is_array($_GET['id_pais'])) {
$paises = $_GET['id_pais'];

foreach ($paises as $id_pais) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM paises WHERE id = $id_pais");
$result = $sql;
}
}
```

La idea es que si por ejemplo el formulario le envía al controlador un arreglo con 4 indices, en el primer ciclo si el indice tuviera un value de 1 que corresponde al id de USA en la tabla paises pues entonces haga la consulta haga  a ese registro, si en el segundo ciclo el indice tuviera un value de 2 que corresponde al id de ESPAÑA en la tabla de paise pues le haga su respectiva consulta a ese registro y así sucesivamente con los demás indices que hay en el arreglo.

Comment: Porque?? no es mas facil hacer un solo query con una clausula in?

Answer (score 2):

puedes convertir tu arreglo a cadena y asi agregarlo a un in en tu consulta

ejemplo:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM paises WHERE id in (".implode(",", $paises).")");
while($result=$sql->fetch_assoc()) accedes a los registros
{
   //$result["nombrecampo"]
}
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta eso era justamente lo que estaba buscando.